# Backtracking Regular Expressions in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

is it possible to form with the .net Regex class backtracking expressions?

is it for example possible, creating a regex which forms braces like in arithmetic formulars? 
like it would accept ( ), ( ( ) ((()())), but not ((, (()(), ()))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it's not called backtracking.

You're looking for [Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

[Backtracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is completely different.